# Spark Out of memory issue : forEachPartition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

[image]

We are processing roughly 500 MB file of data in EMR.

I am performing the following operations on the file.

1. read csv :

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load(s3)
```

2. aggregating by key and creating the list :

```
val data = filteredDf.groupBy($"<key>")
      .agg(collect_list(struct(cols.head, cols.tail: _*)) as "finalData")
      .toJSON
```

3. Iterating through each partition and storing per key aggregation to S3 and sending the key to SQS.

```
data.foreachPartition(partition => {
    partition.foreach(json => ......) 
    }
```

Data is skewed with one account having almost 10M records (~400 MB). I am experiencing out of memory issue during `foreachPartition` for the given account.

```
Configuration:
1 driver : m4.4xlarge CPU Cores : 16 and Memory : 64GB
1 executor : m4.2x large  CPU Cores : 8 and Memory : 32GB

driver-memory: 20G
executor-memory: 10G
Partitions : default 200 [ most of them don't do anything ]
```

Any help is much appreciated! thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Can you try to repartition the data after groupby operation and before using foreachpartition to less number of partitions may be something close to 24 or so and see if you still get. because if you reduce the number of partitions then skew can be reduced. You could also try with Coalesce to see what fits your use case if you don't want to do full shuffle using repartition.

Comment: Thanks Nikunj. One other thing I have noticed is only one executor is being used out of all to read and process the CSV

Comment: if repartition doesn't help - can it be due to the fact that the function passed within the `foreach()` is only available to your driver and, hence, all the data is passed through it? If that's the case, you can try to ship the function(s) to all executors.

Comment: @Jumpo as per the question you have only one executor so only that would get used right?

Comment: added the application user interface screenshot :)

Comment: why so much to the driver?